# Can I bypass an XML load file if it timeouts or can't load?

Tags: php, xml, timeout

I'm reading an XML file and loading it using `new simplexmlelement`.

Sometimes, because the XML file is on a remote server, it can take a long time to load, and sometimes can't load at all if the remote server is down.

Originally I was loading the XML like this:

```
$url = file_get_contents('PATH_TO_XML');
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($url);
```

So I wanted to come up with a way that if the XML file took too long to respond, or couldn't load at all, PHP would just bypass it, load the rest of the website, and just produce a simple error message, wherever the XML file is referenced on the site.

So I read up online, and added this to the code:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'timeout' => 10,
    )
));
$url = file_get_contents(PATH_TO_XML', false, $context);
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($url);
```

But my issue is, that even with this, I'm receiving the following errors when running on my WAMP environment:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.inveroak.co.uk/readerimages/livepanel/91221.xml): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable in C:\wamp\www\clairvoyant\extras\get-readers.php on line 10

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in C:\wamp\www\clairvoyant\extras\get-readers.php on line 11

Exception: String could not be parsed as XML in C:\wamp\www\clairvoyant\extras\get-readers.php on line 11
```

get-readers.php #10:

```
$url = file_get_contents('http://www.inveroak.co.uk/readerimages/livepanel/91221.xml', false, $context);
```

get-readers.php #11:

```
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($url);
```

Is there something I'm missing? Do I need to adapt the referenced points elsewhere in the site?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I think I've actually worked out a good way to do it.

I was going along the right tracks, and I did need to add a condition to every part of the site that included the get-readers.php file.

So what I did was added this to get-readers.php:

```
// create the context
$arContext['http']['timeout'] = 0;
$context = stream_context_create($arContext);

// fetch XML
$url = @file_get_contents('http://www.inveroak.co.uk/readerimages/livepanel/91221.xml', false, $context);
$xmlMsg = '';

if($url === false) { $xmlMsg = "
<div class='xmlError'>
    <span class='title'>Oh no, something's gone wrong!</span>
    <span>We're having trouble showing our available readers at the moment. This is usually only a temporary issue though, and we promise we are working on it!</span><br>
    <span>You can still book a reading by phoning one of our trained operators!</span>
    <div class='action'><div class='inside silver'><span>Pay by card</span>Call <span class='number'>".variable('local_no')."</span> and pay over the phone using a credit or debit card</div></div>
    <div class='action'><div class='inside green'><span>Pay by phone</span>Call <span class='number'>".variable('prem_no')."</span> and pay using your phone bill. It's quick and easy!</div></div>
    <span class='small'>0906 calls cost £1.53/min + network extras. <a href='/terms-conditions'>Full terms &amp; conditions</a></span>
</div>
"; } else { $xml = new SimpleXmlElement($url); } // If XML can't be loaded, show error message
```

Then in every place I was including get-readers.php, right after the include was a foreach to get an array from the XML contents.

I put that into an `IF` statement based on `if($xml)`. And right above that line I echoed `$xmlMsg` to show the error message if it's set. (If the XML file loads, the message is set to `'';`)

Hope that helps someone!